# Show that Laplace transform exists

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Take $f:[0,\infty]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, Riemann integrable on every interval $[0,b]$, and such that there exist $M$, $a$, and $T$, such that $|f(t)|\leq Me^{at}$ for all $t\geq T$. Show that the Laplace transform of $f$ exists. That is, for every $s>a,$ the following integral converges:
$$F(s):=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt. $$

---

Here are my thoughts.

I think I need to use integral comparison test somehow to prove that the integral converges.

It's given that there exist $M$, $a$, and $T$, such that $|f(t)|\leq Me^{at}$ for all $t\geq T$. This can be written as
$$\frac{|f(t)|}{e^{at}}\leq M$$
Now for any $s>a$,
$$\frac{f(t)}{e^{st}}\leq \frac{|f(t)|}{e^{at}}\leq M.$$ 
From here I think I should show that $\int_0^\infty \frac{|f(t)|}{e^{at}}dt$ converges and then using comparison test I can conclude $\int_0^\infty \frac{f(t)}{e^{st}}dt$ converges. How do I show that the integral converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it more sharp. It isn't sufficient to bound $f(t)e^{-st}$ by a constant. But you can use $|f(t)|\leq Me^{at}$ to conclude $|f(t)|e^{-st}\leq Me^{-(s-a)t}$.

Next, we use a very common trick: Assume $f\geq 0$. In that case
$$
\int_0^Rf(t)e^{-st}~dt
$$
is monoton increasing in $R$. Hence, it is sufficient to show that it is bounded independently of $R$. But that can be seen here:
$$
\int_0^Rf(t)e^{-st}~dt=\int_0^Tf(t)e^{-st}~dt+\int_T^Rf(t)e^{-st}~dt\\\leq\int_0^Tf(t)e^{-st}~dt+\int_T^RMe^{-(s-a)t}~dt<\ldots
$$
Next, we use the positive and negative part of a function. Defining $f^+(t)=\max\{f(t),0\}$ and $f^-(t)=-\min\{f(t),0\}$, we get $f(t)=f^+(t)-f^-(t)$ and $f^+,f^-\geq 0$.

Now you can use the argument above and
$$
\int_0^Rf(t)e^{-st}~dt=\int_0^Rf^+(t)e^{-st}~dt-\int_0^Rf^-(t)e^{-st}~dt
$$
to finish the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Assume first that $f \geq 0$. $\int_A^{B} [e^{-st} f(t)]\, dt \leq M\int_A^{B} e^{-(s-a)t}=\, \frac M {s-a} (e^{-(s-a)A}-e^{-(s-a)B})\, $ $\to 0$ as $A,B \to \infty$. This implies that $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t)\, dt$ exists. For the general case you can write $f$ as the difference of two non -negative functions each of which satisfies the hypothesis.

Comment: How does $\int_A^{B} [e^{-st} f(t)]\, dt \leq$ something $\rightarrow 0$ as $A,B\rightarrow \infty$ implies that $\int_0^{\infty} [e^{-st} f(t)]\, dt$ exists?

Comment: If $a_n$ increases to $\infty$ then $\int_0^{a_n} [e^{-st}f(t)]dt$ is  Cauchy sequence, hence convergent. Also the limit is independent of which sequence $\{a_n\}$ you choose.